# How does one place points around a given axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, rotation

I have been searching for solutions for some time because I just can't wrap my head around complex math formulas.

So, I placed a vector in 3D space, with a *position* and a *direction*. Then now I want to place *n* amount of points equally spaced around this vector with the *axis being the direction of the vector*.

I'm working in Unity with C#, but pseudocode or even just an explanation is fine by me.

Edit:

[Here is a picture that I made to show you what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toN02.png)
The sphere is the vector, the arrow is the direction/axis and the
torus is where I want my points to go. I know how to place points around a circle equally spaced, my code for it is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < detail; i++) {
    float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2f / detail;
    Vector3 vert = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Sin(angle) * size, Mathf.Cos(angle) * size);
    verticies[i] = vert + position;
}
```

My main problem is that I don't know 'rotate' the points to the new axis.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So you want points to lie in a circle with center at vector start? Or in some more complex shape? If so, provide some image of the expected result for some N

Answer (score 0):

If you want the points to be around the axis in a circle, you can use the following method:

Calculate the gap between the points in degrees by dividing 360 by the number of points.
Then calculate the position of a point on the circle using its position on the circle (ex: for the 5th point out of 10 points, it is 360/10*5) and the radius of the circle, from this you can simply figure out the position in space using some trigonometry (using Mathf or Math classes).
I hope this helped.